# activity not found exception error

Tags: android

I keep getting the "Activity not found Exception" error message when I try to run the  startActivity in my MenuList.  One of the items on the list launches fine, but the other two give this same error message.  I have checked and re-checked everything and I'm really stuck.

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: You need to share code that starts the activity and AndroidManifest.xml that defines it.

Comment: In the abstract, `ActivityNotFoundException` is one of the simpler ones to understand: you have created an `Intent` that does not match any known activity in the system. However, whether the problem is in the way you are creating the `Intent`, something in your manifest, or something else can't be told from the limited information that you have supplied. Please consider editing your question and including code listings, stack traces, manifests, and other information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I checked my AndroidManifest.xml file and it appears that I just copied and modified some of my newer activities without registering them in the manifest.  I knew it was something simple, but as a newbie it was driving me crazy...Works OK now.  Bill

Answer (score 1):

Double check the path statement of the Activity in your Manifest.  All it takes is one missing period for things not to work!